# Question about "for" and "whenever"

Tags: word-usage

"I watch sitcoms **whenever** I feel sad."

Can this sentence can be paraphrased as: "I watch sitcoms **for** feeling sad"?

Comment: No. The paraphrasing is incorrect. It can be "I watch sitcoms whenever I'm sad" and the equivalent paraphrasing is "I watch sitcoms when I'm sad" or "I watch sitcoms to feel better".

Comment: And note you should pluralize "sitcoms" as Sid had in his comment.

Comment: Technically speaking, constructions like *I drink coffee for staying awake* or *I wear a suit for looking smart* are "syntactically valid", but idiomatically we'd almost always prefer an infinitive verb form ***...to stay awake,  ...to look smart***. Note that those are "unmarked" infinitives - the word ***to*** isn't an infinitive marker, it represents ***in order to** [inf. verb]*.

Comment: Also note that if we "reverse" the cited example to give something that makes more sense, as *I feel sad whenever I watch romcoms*, that doesn't necessarily imply the speaker watches romcoms *in order to* feel sad, any more than *Whenever I gamble I lose* implies I gamble *because* I lose.

Answer (score 1):

> "I watch sitcoms **whenever** I feel sad."

is equivalent to:

> "I watch sitcoms **when** I feel sad."

or

> "I watch sitcoms **if** I feel sad."

or

> "I watch sitcoms **every time when** I feel sad."

These sentences imply that **watching** and **feeling sad** happen at the same time, but there is **no direct cause-effect relationship** between them.

---

On the other hand,

> "I watch sitcoms **for** feeling sad."

is equivalent to:

> "I watch sitcoms **because** feeling sad."

In these case, there is an **explicit direct cause-effect relationship** between **watching** and **feeling sad**.